Expected Breakup Length
The question - A stick is broken into 3 pieces, by randomly choosing two points along its unit length, and cutting it. What is the expected length of the middle part?
So the answer using symmetry is simple, the first ,the middle and the last part have the equal expected lengths (X,Y and Z). Hence  E(X)+E(Y)+E(Z)=1 and E(X)=E(Y)=E(Z)=1/3.
But i tried it with a different method.
Without loss of any generality let x be the coordinate of the first cut and y be the coordinate of the second cut.Let x be the independent coordinate and y be such that it is greater than x.
We aim to find E(y-x)=E(y)-E(x) .As x is independent coordinate , E(x)=0.5
Lets find E(y) .The random variable Y=y is uniformally distributed in the range [x,1], so its cumulative distribution function is $F(Y=y)=\frac{y-x}{1-x}$ and its Probability density function is $f(y)=\frac{1}{1-x}$ . $E(Y=y)=\int_0^1{\int_x^1{\frac{y}{1-x}dx}}=\frac{3}{4}$.So the expectation $E(y-x)=\frac{3}{4}-\frac{2}{4}=0.25$ which is different from $\frac{1}{3}$ .
Why does this method gives different results ?

There are several similar questions to this posts which are already asked. Please check the "Related" section in this page to find them.

I'm sad that this is not about the expected length of a break of a relationship between two humans

The issue is the claim that $x_1$ is distributed uniformly over the interval. It's implicit in your setup that $x_1$ is the smaller of two i.i.d. uniform random variables and so its density isn't uniform over the unit interval.
Call your two numbers $x_1$ and $x_2$ and consider the space of all possible pairs $(x_1, x_2)$. It's the unit square and, to compute probabilities of events in this square, one integrates the constant density 1. We want
$$
P(x_1 \leq x \; | \; x_1 \leq x_2) = \frac{P(x_1 \leq x \mbox{ and } x_1  \leq x_2)}{P(x_1 \leq x_2)}.
$$
Viewed as a subset of the unit square, the set of points $(x_1, x_2)$ that correspond to the event whose probability appears in the numerator $P(x_1 \leq x \mbox{ and } x_1  \leq x_2)$ is a four-sided polygon that's bounded by:

the left edge of the square, where $x_1 = 0$;
the top edge of the square, where $x_2 = 1$;
the vertical line $x_1 = x$ and
the diagonal line $x_1 = x_2$.

This polygon has area $\frac{1}{2} - \frac{(1-x)^2}{2}$ (see the figure below).

The set of points that correspond to the event whose probability gives the denominator  $P(x_1 \leq x_2)$ is the right triangle with corners at $(0,0), \,(0,1)$ and $(1,1)$ and it has area 1/2. Thus the cumulative density function for $x_1$ is given by
$$
F_1(x) = P(x_1 \leq x \; | \; x_1 \leq x_2) = \frac{1/2 - (1 - x)^2/2}{1/2} = 2x - x^2.
$$
The probability density function for $x_1$ is thus $f_1(x) = \frac{dF_1}{dx} = 2 - 2x$ and the expected value of $x_1$ is
$$
E(x_1) = \int_0^1 x f_1(x) \, dx = \int_0^1 x(2 - 2x) \, dx = \left[x^2 -\frac{2x^3}{3}\right]_0^1 = \frac{1}{3}.
$$
Similar reasoning shows that $E(x_2) = 2/3$ and so $E(x_2 - x_1) = E(x_2) - E(x_1) = 1/3$, as you'd expected.
